# trying to install gnome "Unable to locate package tigervnc-standalone-server"

Tags: linux, debian, gnome

I'm trying to remote my debian VPS (so I could connect to it via remote desktop).

I'm new to this so I'm following a tutorial and after `apt-get update` I did `apt-get install -y task-gnome-desktop` (it took about 3 hours to complete) now when I try `apt install -y xrdp tigervnc-standalone-server` this is what i get:

```
root@addy:~# apt install -y xrdp tigervnc-standalone-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package tigervnc-standalone-server
```

what is the problem?
any other good tutorial?
Thanks.

Comment: you can try to install tightvncserver instead of tigervnc-standalone-server if you're using Debian 8

Answer (score 2):

The message is telling you that there's no such package as "tigervnc-standalone-server" in the repositories you have configured your package management system to use. It might just be an incorrect name, or you need
to acquire the package from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

An old post - but this is how:

Go to Debian (same as Ubuntu more or less)

http://neuro.debian.net/install_pkg.html?p=tigervnc-standalone-server

Click select your os and download server

then add the repo to Ubuntu - together with the key

Something like:

```
wget -O- http://neuro.debian.net/lists/jessie.de-m.libre | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/neurodebian.sources.list
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 0xA5D32F012649A5A9
```

followed by

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 1):

The tigervnc packages exist in the `universe` repository.
Add the `universe` repo through:

> sudo add-apt-repository universe

Then search for (or install) `tigervnc-standalone-server` through:

> sudo apt install tigervnc-standalone-server

Answer (score 0):

You can search for packages on the Ubuntu website:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=tigervnc-standalone-server

There you will see only bionic, artful and zesty have the package tigervnc-standalone-server. A VPS will probably be using a Long Term Support version, which is 16.04 LTS (Xenial)

Verify which version you're using:

```
 cat /etc/*release
```

Then you can search "ubuntu YOURVERSION vnc server", which is always wise to add to your searches.